# sprintf doesn't work well

Tags: php, printf

I wish that the number "9239" appears "9.24".
Ditto for "9.2" displays "9.20".
Ditto for "10" appears "10.00" ...

I use

`$carat = sprintf ('%02d.2f', $carat);`

But this does not

Can you help me?

Comment: Why would `9239` display `9.24` but `10` display `10.00`?

Comment: Yeah, that makes no sense. I guess he means 9200 and 1000 as input values though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you have a good look at the number_format() function

Exampel taken from php.net is as follows

```
<?php

$number = 1234.56;

// english notation (default)
$english_format_number = number_format($number);
// 1,235

// French notation
$nombre_format_francais = number_format($number, 2, ',', ' ');
// 1 234,56

$number = 1234.5678;

// english notation without thousands separator
$english_format_number = number_format($number, 2, '.', '');
// 1234.57

?>
```

May I also suggest that there is a function specifically for money, [money_format()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)

The money_format() function adapts according to your [setLocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).

[number_format() on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: Consider rewording it so it's more of an answer than a comment... I.e. put some actual code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that using just `printf` formatting. Convert it to the appropriate number first:

```
$carat = sprintf('%.02f', $carat / 1000);
```

Demo:

```
php > printf("%.02f\n", 9239 / 1000);
9.24
php > printf("%.02f\n", 9200 / 1000);
9.20
```

Comment: This doesn't work for `$carat = 10`.

Comment: Most likely the OP posted nonsense in this regard.